# Notify Function when there are changes in the materials of any of the scene objects

Tags: python, materials

To clarify by "changes in the materials" i mean on a material_slot level not as in node changes in the actual material; it should be called when adding, removing, or renaming not-None material_slots

I'm currently working with a UI List that has all the material in the scene and is updating accordingly to the materials of every object, but I'm running into problems when it comes to calling the update automatically, I've tried already depsgraph_update_post and did not work, I've looked a bit and seems the msgbus is the only option, but anything other than the active_material property on bpy.types.Object
fails to call the function with no error given

this is what i tried using that fails to update at every change, leaving the UI List to be out of date or not updated at all requiring a new material to be created to call the update:

```
bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(AlxMaterialRegisterChanges)
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key=(bpy.types.Object, "material_slots"), owner="owner", args=(), notify=AlxMaterialRegisterChanges)
```

manual update is how i'm currently handling it but it has the same issue as the msgbus where if pressed too soon before the update finishes the list will be out of date or newly created materials will be missing entirely